# Why is Qantas spelt カンタス?

Tags: katakana, loanwords, spelling

At first I thought that Japanese people pronouncing Qantas as カンタス was an urban legend (the start of "カンタス" matches a vulgar four letter word in English), but I've since found out that it's real, with Qantas' Japanese homepage having "カンタス航空｜ホームページ｜航空券｜旅行情報 - Qantas".

By contrast, there's almost always a "w" style sound when Australians pronounce it. Wiktionary gives an IPA of /ˈkwɒntəs/, and the second sentence of the [Japanese edition of Wikipedia's article on the airline](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AB%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B9%E8%88%AA%E7%A9%BA) mentions how Australians pronounce it with three citations.

Why is Qantas spelt "カンタス" in Japanese?

As far as I can tell, it isn't because it resembles how non-Australian English speakers pronounce the word - in the American movie "Rain Man" they pronounce it with a "w" sound.

"カンタス" could be seen as matching a phonetic spelling of "Qantas", like how English-speakers pronounce "Qatar", but I thought katakana was typically based on how words are actually pronounced.

Alternatively, is it possible that katakana lacks the capability of indicating the "w" sound in this scenario?

Comment: Fun question as usual, but English-speakers have done the exact same with our word 「怪談{かいだん}」: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kwaidan_(film)

Comment: @l'électeur I always assumed the spelling of that title was due to the rending of 怪 as くわい prior to mid-century spelling reforms in Japanese.

Comment: 期待する答えは何ですか。このサイトでなく、カンタス航空の本社に理由をお聞きください。

Comment: @mackygoo I'm assuming that native speakers of Japanese would have determined the pronunciation of the Japanese word for Qantas, rather than a focus group belonging to Qantas HQ. Qantas has been flying to Japan since [1947](http://australianaviation.com.au/2017/07/qantas-returns-to-osaka-kansai-with-seasonal-sydney-services/), and I don't think such a focus group would have existed back then.

Comment: given that "kw" would be an unusual pronunciation in modern japanese, how might you have expected qantas to be rendered in japanese?

Comment: @A.Ellett Maybe something starting with "ク", like with "クイーン".

Comment: native speakers of Japaneseがカンタス航空の日本名を決めたのは間違いないと思いますが、それは「大阪城は大工が建てた」と言っているのと同じで間違いです。「大阪城は豊臣秀吉が建てた」が正解です。従って固有名詞であるカンタス航空の名前はオーストラリアにある本社が回答する専権事項であってこのサイトで議論する内容ではありません。あなたの質問としては、例えば、「wi, wu, we, wo; qua, qui, qu, que ,quoなどに対応するカタカナがないが、＊＊＊ですか」のようにするべきではないでしょうか。

Comment: @mackygoo unfortunately my Japanese isn't good enough to understand your comment, and I wasn't able to understand your comment with the help of Google translate either.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: It might be correct to say that native speakers of Japanese have decided the Japanese name of Qantas Airways, but it is the same mistake as saying "Osaka Castle was built by carpenters." "Osaka Castle was built by Toyotomi Hideyoshi" is the correct answer. Therefore the Japanese name of Qantas Airways, a proper noun, is an exclusive matter responding to the headquarters in Australia, not one to be discussed at this site. As for your question, I know you have plentiful humor and knowledge to post a smarter question without using examples of four letter word or Qantas Airways.

Comment: I've always wondered myself how to pronounce "Qantas".  And, I can't find anything that provides an *official pronunciation*.  In many other English language contexts where there's no "u" following "q", we don't insert a "u":  e.g. Qatar, qi, burqa, etc.  Could it be that the original intended pronunciation of "Qantas" was "kantas"?  But because we're so used to seeing "q" and reading "kw" that "Qantas" became "kwantas".  Hence I'm inclined to agree with @mackygoo 's insistence to contact Qanta and ask headquarters itself what their official line is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not impossible to render is as クワンタス but it's not really commercially advantageous to adopt such a peculiar pronunciation. After all, I don't know how they decided their own name since it's a proper noun like mackygoo says.